# Open Stack and Development Stack

Tags: openstack, devstack

i am really confuse about  the main difference between Open Stack and development Stack ? 
is it different version  or different platform ?

Comment: please edit your question and add more information to your question. also, you can add some code and effort and result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's get the terminology correct.  You are talking about OpenStack (one word) and DevStack (one word).

OpenStack is a suite of services for managing computing and related resources.  You typically use it for managing "cloud computing" resources, consisting of multiple physical compute and storage servers.  Setting up a system like this for production use on "real" hardware takes a lot of time and expertise.

DevStack is a essentially a set of scripts that will set up set up a simple OpenStack test environment running as virtual machines on (typically) a Linux PC with a few GB of RAM and a chunk of free disk space.  The purpose is to allow a developer to set up a tiny cloud for trying things out, and doing service development work.

OpenStack and DevStack are neither different versions or different platforms.  They are different parts of a larger whole.  (You could say that DevStack is part of the OpenStack suite of software.  Development of OpenStack and DevStack are handled by the same umbrella organization under the same governance, etc, etc.)